# Analyse audio files with Python

Tags: python, audio

I actually have Photodiode connect to my PC an do capturing with Audacity.

I want to improve this by using an old RPI1 as dedicated test station. As result the shutter speed should appear on the console. I would prefere a python solution for getting signal an analyse it.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? I played around with oct2py, but i dont really under stand how to calculate the time between the two peak of the signal.

[image: Shutter Signal]

Comment: Hmmm I think you should show us what you get with `oct2py` at least. The perfect thing would be to know where to find the inputs here which are your audio files

Answer (score 1):

I have no expertise on sound analysis with Python and this is what I found doing some internet research as far as I am interested by this topic

#### pyAudioAnalysis for an eponym purpose

You  an use pyAudioAnalysis developed by  Theodoros Giannakopoulos

Towards your end, function `mtFileClassification()` from audioSegmentation.py can be a good start. This function

- splits an audio signal to successive mid-term segments and extracts mid-term feature statistics from each of these sgments, using `mtFeatureExtraction()` from `audioFeatureExtraction.py`
- classifies each segment using a pre-trained supervised model
  merges successive fix-sized segments that share the same class label to larger segments
- visualize statistics regarding the results of the segmentation - classification process.

For instance

```
from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS
[flagsInd, classesAll, acc, CM] = aS.mtFileClassification("data/scottish.wav","data/svmSM", "svm", True, 'data/scottish.segments')
```

Note that the last argument of this function is a .segment file. This is used as ground-truth (if available) in order to estimate the overall performance of the classification-segmentation method. If this file does not exist, the performance measure is not calculated. These files are simple comma-separated files of the format: ,,. For example:

```
0.01,9.90,speech
9.90,10.70,silence
10.70,23.50,speech
23.50,184.30,music
184.30,185.10,silence
185.10,200.75,speech
 ...
```

If I have well understood your question this is at least what you want to generate isn't it ? I rather think you have to provide it there.

Most of these information are directly quoted from his wiki which I suggest you to read it. Yet don't hesitate to reach out as far as I am really interested by this topic

#### Other available libraries for audio analysis :

[image]